# is it possible to use NCHW format on CPU?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use NCHW ie channel first data format in my cpu. It is a maxpool layer as a part of Resnet18.

```
MaxPooling2D(pool_size=[3, 3], strides=2, padding='same', data_format='channels_first')
```

And the error i am getting is:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Default MaxPoolingOp only supports NHWC on device type CPU
     [[Node: max_pooling2d_3/MaxPool = MaxPool[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", ksize=[1, 1, 3, 3], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 2, 2], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](batch_normalization_51/cond/Merge)]]
```

Is there a way to fix this? I have also tried `data_format="NCHW"` but it gave the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with a simple model to debug the issue? This works on my system with CPU.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=[3, 3], strides=2, padding='same', 
                    data_format='channels_first', input_shape=(3,224,224)))
model.summary()
X = np.random.randn(1,3,224,224)
Y = model.predict(X)
print(Y.shape)
(1, 3, 112, 112)
```

Comment: it stopped giving that error when tensorflow compiled on intel mkl, thanks.

Comment: @newlearnershiv please consider posting a short answer, so that the thread is useful for others in the future - otherwise it may better to just delete the question

Comment: From @newlearnershiv 's comment, I found this helpful link software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/… (In summary, pip install intel-tensorflow and pip uninstall tensorflow)

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install intel-tensorflow
```

solved the problem, but the training seems to be slower than before.